# How to prove $\langle F(x)-F(y),x-y \rangle_{X^*\times X}\ge(\|x\|-\|y\|)^2 $?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

X - reflexive Banah space. Let $F: X\to X^*$ be a duality mapping. How to prove the following inequality

$$\langle F(x)-F(y),x-y \rangle_{X^*\times X}\ge(\|x\|-\|y\|)^2 ?$$

Comment: Does $X$ and $X^*$ being stricly convex change anything?

Comment: can you write down the definition of a duality mapping, please?

Comment: The operator $F:X\to \mathcal{P(X^*)}$ defined by 
$$Fx=\{x^*\in X^*\,|\,\langle x^*,x \rangle=\|x\|^2=\|x^*\|^2 \}$$
is called duality mapping of X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the notation $F(x)$ in the question stands for a generic element in the set of the duality map defined in the comments above. So using the fact that for $f\in X^*$ and $z\in X$ we have $|\langle f,z\rangle_{X^*\times X}|\le\|f\|_{X^*}\|z\|_X$, then:

$$\begin{align} \langle F(x)-F(y),x-y\rangle_{X^*\times X}&=\|x\|_X^2+\|y\|_X^2-\langle F(x),y\rangle_{X^*\times X}-\langle F(y),x\rangle_{X^*\times X}\ge\\&\ge  \|x\|_X^2+\|y\|_X^2 -\|F(x)\|_{X^*}\|y\|_X-\|F(y)\|_{X^*}\|x\|_X = \\&=\|x\|_X^2+\|y\|_X^2 -\|x\|_X\|y\|_X-\|y\|_X\|x\|_X =\\&=(\|x\|-\|y\|)^2.
\end{align}$$